# Bootstrap - tab with dropdown, activation issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, tabs, dropdown

I have a problem with the activation of my tab links, if you try the code you'll see that when I click on "Home" for example it activate correctly but if I click on "Menu 1" after this, "Home" will still be activate and "Menu 1" too, so I won't be able to click on "home" another time...

```
<div class="container dropdown">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Click to choose a channel<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu nav">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I got everything ! No one helped, it took me time but I learned from this :P I'll post it just in case someone need the answer :

`$('input').val($(this).children().html());`

So the final code is :

```
<div class="container dropdown">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="string" min="1" placeholder="Choose a channel" id="channel">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Click to chose a menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu nav">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add the `<script>` :

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $('input').val($(this).children().html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After hard working on it, I found an easy way to do it :

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
})
```

I just added this line
`<input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" type="string" min="1" placeholder="Choose a channel" id="channel">`

and now i'd like to know if it's possible to make the input value at the 'h3' tag of the 'li' selected ? Something like that :

`$('input').val(this.val());`

My input value will be "Menu 2" if we click on the "Menu 2" on the list. Thanks for helping.